# Maven file template in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, velocity, file-templates

recently I wanted to change the default maven pom file when I create a maven project in IntelliJ. So I went into the settings and edited the template.

But as I'm here, it doesn't work very well.

Every time I try to create a new maven project (and so that the template is used), I get the following error:

> named capturing group is missing trailing '}'

So I guess there's a format problem in my template but I can't find where it comes from.

Here's what I did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

#if (${HAS_PARENT})
    <parent>
        <groupId>${PARENT_GROUP_ID}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${PARENT_ARTIFACT_ID}</artifactId>
        <version>${PARENT_VERSION}</version>
#if (${HAS_RELATIVE_PATH})
        <relativePath>${PARENT_RELATIVE_PATH}</relativePath>
#end
    </parent>
#end
    <groupId>${GROUP_ID}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${ARTIFACT_ID}</artifactId>
    <version>${VERSION}</version>

   <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>9</java.version>
        <main.class><!-- TODO --></main.class>
    </properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                            <finalName>${DS}{project.artifactId}</finalName>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${DS}{main.class}</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${DS}{java.version}</source>
                    <target>${DS}{java.version}</target>
                    <release>${DS}{java.version}</release>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy file="${DS}{basedir}/target/${DS}{project.artifactId}.jar" tofile="${DS}{copy.build.path}/${DS}{project.artifactId}.jar"/>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>mrcraftcod.write</id>
            <url>${DS}{mrcraftcod.write.url}</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <repositories>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Thank if for you help.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please report an issue on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: I opened an issue on their tracker, if something happens over there I'll update here too.